# Access Denied while fetching Bitlocker Information using WMI Query in VB.NET in Local system

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I am developing a VB.NET application to fetch the Bitelocker Information from local system. Below is my code. This code works perfectly and returns the results when I run with admin privileges. But it is giving error while running without admin access.

```
Dim arEncryptionMethod = {"None", "AES 128 With Diffuser", "AES 256 With Diffuser", _
    "AES 128", "AES 256"}
Dim arProtectionStatus = {"Protection Off", "Protection On", "Protection Unknown"}
Dim strComputer = "."

Dim colItems As New ManagementObjectSearcher("\\" & strComputer & _
    "\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption",
    "Select * from Win32_EncryptableVolume " & "Where DriveLetter='C:'")

For Each objItem As ManagementObject In colItems.Get()
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume:" & objItem("DriveLetter"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(" EncryptionMethod: " & arEncryptionMethod(objItem.InvokeMethod _
        ("GetEncryptionMethod", Nothing, Nothing)("EncryptionMethod")))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(" ProtectionStatus: " & arProtectionStatus(objItem.InvokeMethod _
        ("GetProtectionStatus", Nothing, Nothing)("ProtectionStatus")))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your program `Administrator` privileges by editing the `RequestedExecutionLevel` under your application. You need to show all files under your solution, look for `app.manifest`.

Change Default: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

**TO**

```
  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Also on another note, when you open this file up it should have notes in there explaining what types you can change it to.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried this already and the thing is that if we change the level as "requireAdministrator", when we run the application, It will ask for admin credentials to execute in systems with limited user accounts. Kindly let me know is there any other way to do this. I suspect its due to the more secure nature of Bitlocker. I am able to use all the other classes except the "Win32_EncryptableVolume".